# Scheduling a recurring alarm/event

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a class that extends Application. In the class I make a call to AlarmManager and pass in an intent. As scheduled my EventReceiver class, that extends BroadcastReceiver, processes the call in the onReceive method. How would I call the intent again from the onReceive method to schedule another event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setRepeating()` instead of `set()`, to have it recur automatically. Or, just create another `PendingIntent` on an equivalent `Intent` (same action, same `Uri`, same component, etc.). You do not need the original `PendingIntent` object each time.

Comment: I don't believe I can use set repeating since the times will vary and I need to get the next in my queue.It would be nice if there was a way to use the same intent and schedule events to occur at varying times. For example if I have an array of times that I would like to pass in and not have to chain the events one after another.

Comment: Then use several slightly different `Intents` and schedule them all in a block. By "slightly different", they have to differ by more than the extras, otherwise they will be equivalent from `PendingIntent`'s standpoint. If you are using an `Intent` that specifies the component (i.e., it takes a `Class` as the 2nd parameter to the constructor), then just tuck in a unique action string, and that will keep them distinct yet not interfere with your receipt.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 30000;//milliseconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);
```

More complete sample can be found in Photostream sample application http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/.